# dpkg-query vs apt-cache: different package lists?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, dpkg

I noticed an interesting phenomenon and I am looking for an explanation. On my Ubuntu 15.10 (alpha) system, `dpkg-query` cannot find some uninstalled packages which `apt-cache` can find. For instance,

```
dpkg-query -l libssl-dev
```

gives me:

```
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libssl-dev
```

while:

```
apt-cache show libssl-dev
```

finds the package information. At the same time, `dpkg-query` can locate other uninstalled packages, e.g. gimp and show their status as uninstalled. Why are some packages not visible to `dpkg-query`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dpkg-query` is primarily intended to work on packages present on the system (including packages in various states, from installed, unpacked to packages that have been removed but not yet purged), or packages that have selections, for example a non-installed package marked for installation. A package purged and without any selections will be garbage collected from the `dpkg` *status* file, and will not be shown by default by `dpkg-query`. You can still ask it to show available packages from repositories by using the `--load-avail` option, as long as your *available* file is up-to-date that will also give good results. See this [FAQ](https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg/FAQ#Q:_Why_does_.27.27dpkg_--set-selections.27.27_not_record_selections_for_unknown_packages.3F) entry for more information on how to do that.

`apt-cache` is intended to be used for both installed packages and packages available from the configured repositories for `apt`, in contrast to other possible `dpkg` frontends.